# C++20 Member Initialization List Clang++ vs G++

Tags: c++, gcc, clang

Currently using Clang++ 13.0.0 and GCC G++ 11.2.0.

The code below has been simplified for context. When I run the code using g++, it runs without any warnings or errors. When I run the code using Clang, I get the following error:

`field 'cat' is uninitialized when used here [-Werror,-Wuninitialized]`

Is there any way to resolve this?

Code:

```
struct Bar {
    Object *ptr;
    int y;
};

struct Foo {
    Object *ptr;
    Bar cat;
};

class Test {
    Foo animal;

    Test()
    : animal{
          generateObject(),
          {
             animal.ptr,
             0 
          }
      }
    {}
};
```

Comment: `cat{0, 0}` :-)

Comment: Well, `cat{0, 0}` would be an obvious way to resolve this.

Comment: But what if I needed to use cat.x? Would I have to take a different approach to avoid this situation? Or is it fine as long as it compiles with just g++?

Comment: @Locklan: Clang is right, as it would be UB. `cat.x` is not yet initialized. gcc just doesn't spot the issue.

Comment: Why would you need to use `cat.x`, especially before it has been initialized?

Comment: @Eljay Sorry, changed it to struct.

Comment: C++ compilers are not required to produce a warning (or *warning turned into error* in the case of `-Werror`) for reading an uninitialized variable.  Both Clang and GCC will do that for many situations, but that kind of static analysis is not guaranteed nor comprehensive — and is not required by the C++ standard.  It's a useful tool for the situations that can be diagnosed, but is still a (good) crutch.  Other static analysis tools like Coverity which are not time constrained can do a deeper analysis.

Comment: You turned a [mcve] into something that doesn't in fact compile. That didn't add any clarity. Anyway, I was [unable to reproduce the warning](https://godbolt.org/z/KaPTa8K51) with your original code. Nor can I [with the new example](https://godbolt.org/z/rP5saKEeW), fixed to get it to compile.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I added the object pointers to try and show why I needed to use `cat.x`, but now the code has become irreproducible...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible approach:

```
class Test {
private:
  explicit Test(Object* ptr)
  : animal{ptr, {ptr, 0}} {}
public:
  Test() : Test(generateObject()) {}
};
```

Comment: May I ask what the explicit keyword does?

Comment: It prevents a one-parameter constructor from being used as a converting constructor, for implicit conversions. Not strictly necessary here (as the constructor is private and unlikely to be used by accident). It's just a habit that's been drilled into me to the point I do it without thinking, to add `explicit` whenever declaring a one-parameter constructor (unless I deliberately want a converting one, of course; then I would add a comment to that effect).